# Need direction on automating the process of copying and pasting a shape

Tags: inkscape, copy-and-paste

I'm trying to automate the process of pasting a box over some existing text on a pdf. For each new pdf I would like to cover some text in a light gray box, so the end result is that the text is not shown. I want to be able to make a tool that will pull in 50 pdfs, have a gray box cover the text, and then have them saved. What I'm looking for is some direction on how I can automate the process. For example, are there some tutorials or methods you would suggest I look into? [image: Text that I want to cover with box] [image: pdf image that I would like to automate for each new pdf]

Comment: Is the art vector or raster? Is the box in the exact same position for every piece of artwork? It *may* be easier to remove the text than to add a box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the art is vector and the box will be in the same position each time. The challenge for me to remove text each time is that I want to automate the process and I think that may be more challenging, but I'm a novice. so maybe not.